# From A New Android Developer: I have been getting the error message "Gradle Sync Failed: The first result from the daemon was empty"

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Please, I will be happy to have anyone explain this to me in a "not too" technical way. I have checked out other answers given but they don't work.Even YouTube instructional videos did not give adequate answers. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gradle runs in a separate JVM (called the daemon) which it starts up whenever you run a Gradle task (or run a build from IntelliJ).  Seems like the daemon is not able to start up.  This sometimes happens if you don't have enough memory or the parameters to start the JVM are bad (try looking in "gradle.properties").

You could debug this further by running "gradlew" from the Terminal with the "--debug" option which may give you more info on what is happening.